# Will #if RELEASE work like #if DEBUG does in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

In all the examples I've seen of the #if compiler directive, they use "DEBUG".  Can I use "RELEASE" in the same way to exclude code that I don't want to run when compiled in debug mode? The code I want to surround with this block sends out a bunch of emails, and I don't want to accidentally send those out when testing.

Comment: `#if !DEBUG` serves the same function as `#if RELEASE` would've.  Alternatively, `#if DEBUG` then `#else` then `#endif` if there's different code to run in the modes.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

No, it won't, unless you do some work.

The important part here is what DEBUG really is, and it's a kind of constant defined that the compiler can check against.

If you check the project properties, under the Build tab, you'll find three things:

- A text box labelled "Conditional compilation symbols"
- A check box labelled "Define DEBUG constant"
- A check box labelled "Define TRACE constant"

There is no such checkbox, nor constant/symbol pre-defined that has the name RELEASE.

However, you can easily add that name to the text box labelled Conditional compilation symbols, but make sure you set the project configuration to Release-mode before doing so, as these settings are per configuration.

So basically, unless you add that to the text box, `#if RELEASE` won't produce any code under any configuration.

Answer (score 433):

`RELEASE` is not defined, but you can use

```
#if (!DEBUG)
  ...
#endif
```

Comment: It isn't, but of course you can use the NOT operator like that. Didn't think of that when I wrote my answer.

Comment: It does, but using your solution is clearer and "more correct", IMHO.

Comment: Especially since you can have more configurations than just RELEASE and DEBUG -- for some of my projects there is DEBUG, RELEASE, and DEPLOY or DEV (DEBUG), TEST, and PROD (RELEASE)

Comment: For anyone else confused by the comments above, the unedited answer wondered if `RELEASE` was defined.

Answer (score 46):

Nope.

While in debug configuration there is a `DEBUG` defined constant (automatically defined by Visual Studio) while there is no such constant defined for release mode. Check your project settings under build.

Selecting [Define DEBUG constant] under *Project -> Build* is like including #define DEBUG at the beginning of every file.

If you want to define a RELEASE constant for the release configuration go to:

- Project Properties -> Build
- Select Release Mode
- in the *Conditional compilation symbols* textbox enter: RELEASE

Comment: Found this very useful as I have now defined a RELEASE constant for my Release configuration and a TESTING constant for my Testing configuration. Very useful for defining require https only for release `#if (RELEASE) [RequireHttps] #endif`

Answer (score 37):

On my VS install (VS 2008) `#if RELEASE` does not work. However you could just use `#if !DEBUG`

Example:

```
#if !DEBUG
SendTediousEmail()
#endif
```

Answer (score 10):

I've never seen that before...but I have seen:

```
#if (DEBUG == FALSE)
```

and

```
#if (!DEBUG)
```

That work for ya?

Comment: Preprocessor symbols do not have values in C#; they are just "defined" or "not defined". So only the `!` operator will work, as in your second example.

Comment: According to MSDN, you _can_ use operators like == to test for true or false. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Answer (score 9):

You can use `#if(!DEBUG)` for this purposes.

Comment: Good save for me was wanting to use this in xamrian thanks for posting.

Answer (score 4):

"Pop Catalin" got it right. Controlling the definition based on the type of build provides a great deal of flexibility. For example, you can have a "DEBUG", "DEMO", and "RELEASE" configuration all in the same solution. That prevents the need for duplicate programming with two different solutions.

So yes `#if RELEASE` or `#if (RELEASE)` works the same as `#if DEBUG` when the RELEASE Conditional compilation symbol is defined.

The following is taken from "Pop Catalin" post:
If you want to define a RELEASE constant for the release configuration go to:
    * Project *Properties -> Build*
    * Select Release Mode
    * in the *Conditional compilation symbols* textbox enter: RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but it might be worth mentioning that you can create your own configurations outside of DEBUG and RELEASE, such as TEST or UAT.

If then on the Build tab of the project properties page you then set the "Conditional compilation symbols" to TEST (for instance) you can then use a construct such as

```
#if (DEBUG || TEST )
    //Code that will not be executed in RELEASE or UAT
#endif
```

You can use this construct for specific reason such as different clients if you have the need, or even entire Web Methods for instance. We have also used this in the past where some commands have caused issues on specific hardware, so we have a configuration for an app when deployed to hardware X.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
#If CONFIG = "Release" Then

....

#End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own conditional compile-time symbols (any name you like).
Go to the "project Build dialog", located in the project properties box,
menu option: Project->[projectname] Properties...

You can also define them "at the top of the C# code file". Like:

```
#define RELEASE
// or
#undef RELEASE
```

you can use the symbol in a #if statement:

```
#if RELEASE
// code ...
#elif …
// code ...
#endif

// or

#if !RELEASE
// code ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst [M4N's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/507723/361842) (`#if (!DEBUG)`) makes most sense, another option could be to use the preprocessor to amend other flag's values; e.g.

```
bool isRelease = true;
#if DEBUG
    isRelease = false;
#endif
```

Or better, rather than referring to whether we're in release or debug mode, use flags that define the expected behavior and set them based on the mode:

```
bool sendEmails = true;
#if DEBUG
    sendEmails = false;
#endif
```

This is different to using preprocessor flags, in that the flags are still there in production, so you incur the overhead of `if (sendEmails) {/* send mails */}` each time that code's called, rather than the code existing in release but not existing in debug, but this can be advantageous; e.g. in your tests you may want to call your `SendEmails()` method but on a mock, whilst running in debug to get additional output.

Answer (score -8):

why not just

```
#if RELEASE
#undef DEBUG
#endif
```

Comment: There's no constant named RELEASE defined by Visual Studio under release mode.

Comment: `/d:RELEASE` would also work. You could also add this to conditional compilation symbols under Release configuration (project properties build tab).