# Enable code on Release compilation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have code which I would like to enable for compilation when I build project using Release configuration and disable while debugging. How to do what?

Comment: Check out this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507704/will-if-release-work-like-if-debug-does-in-c

Comment: Do you mean "while debugging", or do you mean "for the debug build"?  The build configuration you use is completely unrelated to whether or not you are using a debugger - make sure you understand the distinction.

Comment: Yes, you can debug release builds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [preprocessor directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx).

```
#IF ! DEBUG
//Your code here
#ENDIF
```

Though, if your code is full of these, you may want to consider other options, such as

Another alternative is to use the [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) on a method so it will only be used if a specific symbol has been defined:

```
[Conditional("RELEASE")]
public void MyReleaseMethod()
{
}
```

Comment: But to use Conditional("RELEASE") you need to add "RELEASE" to your Conditional compilation symbols in the Build tab of your project properties. "DEBUG" is there by default for debug builds, but "RELEASE" isnt.

Comment: I would also suggest `#if DEBUG` / `[Conditional("DISABLED")]` / `#endif` to make a method "release-only" without adding additional symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Use a preprocessor directive. Surround the code with:

```
#if !DEBUG

// Release-only code goes here...

#endif
```

In the standard debug and release configurations in Visual Studio, the `DEBUG` symbol is defined when compiling in debug and not in release, so code in between the two directives above will only be compiled in release mode.

If you need to do one thing in debug and another thing in release, you can do this:

```
#if DEBUG

// Debug-only code goes here...

#else

// Release-only code goes here...

#endif
```

See the [C# preprocessor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more details.