# Change Behavior when not RELEASE build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, configuration-files

What is the best way to change behavior between DEV, TEST, and RELEASE builds?

I have an application that sends emails to recipients stored in a database.  When developing and testing I would like to override the desired behavior and send the email to the person using the application (e.g. the developer or tester).

When we go to production, I would like to of course send it to the email coming from the database.

I considered adding a RELEASE constant as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507704/will-if-release-work-like-if-debug-does-in-c)

Does anyone have some advice on the best way to achieve this or a suggestion as to a better way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap email send functionality with an interface, say `INotifier.Send()`. Implement it in several ways:

- `EmailNotifier : INotifier` for release (send email)
- `LocalNotifier : INotifier` for debug (write into console)
- `MockNotifier : INotifier` for test (assert some conditions)

Put class's type into configuration-specific config and read and invoke it by notification send module. See [Web.config transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx).

Comment: I second this strategy because often you need to be able to test the RELEASE build (the version compiled when there is RELEASE and no DEBUG conditional compilation symbol) in a test environment and having something whose behavior varies by web.config achieves that.

Comment: This approach seems excellent.  However, I've only ever used transforms for connection strings.  How would one swap a class?

Comment: Looks like I can use something like Activator.CreateInstance

Comment: @Shawn: Extend any key into config with configuration-dependent attribute, e.g. `<add name="x" configuration="y" value="z" />>` and determine using XPath or LINQ

Comment: Try to use [XmlPreprocess](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET, you could have web.config settings that change based on the current publish configuration.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx](http://How%20to%3a%20Transform%20Web.config%20When%20Deploying%20a%20Web%20Application%20Project)

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" 
      connectionString="ReleaseSQLServer" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

In our projects we add keys like "Environment" and "EmailsToInTestEnvironment" to config file. In "Environment" we specify either "production" or "test" and if it is "test", the application replaces original email with the ones listed in "EmailsToInTestEnvironment".

To make it simple and realistic, the replacement occurs in the method sending email, not in methods calling it. Original address gets replaced right before the email goes out, and once once the email is sent, original email address is being returned back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [XmlPreprocess tool](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/) for config files manipulation. It is using one mapping file for multiple environments. You can edit mapping file by Excel. It is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done by using separate config files for your application.  Visual studio already provides debug and release separation for you.  If by test you mean unit test, then the test project that's loading your app will be able to use its own config file there.