# How do I detect a custom configuration?

Tags: wpf, configuration

I have a WPF application with three custom configurations. The are as follows:

- Debug
- Deploy_Local
- Deploy_Beta
- Deploy_Live

Obviously I can use a precompiler directive to detect Debug:

```
#if DEBUG
    // Debug code
#else
    // Non-debug code
#endif
```

How can I do this with the the remaining three configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was answered somewhat in: [Will #if RELEASE work like #if DEBUG does in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507704/will-if-release-work-like-if-debug-does-in-c)

Basically, you do need to also define custom symbols at the project level (in the build tab). So if you name your configuration `MY_CONFIG`, you will have to add the `MY_CONFIG` symbol to all the project that you want to handle that configuration specifically. You can then do the same construct as:

```
#if MY_CONFIG
    Console.WriteLine("MY_CONFIG");
#endif
```

Hope this helps,

Eric.

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with:

```
#if DEBUG

#else
    #if Deploy_Local
    // and so on
    #endif
#endif
```

Comment: Does that work?  Does the value 'Deploy_Local' actually exist?

Comment: ah thats the problem, you want to define custom variables..... sorry can't help you then, I got no idea what's wpf is, thought this would be plain c/c++

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own.  There is a "Conditional Compilation Symbols" in the "Build" tab of the project's settings.  It's at least there in WPF applications.  I added the precompiler symbols for each of my configurations therein.

I really hate giving the Answer to myself.  *Sigh!*  So can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: sorry, started answering before you posted your answer. Oh well, glad you figured it out.