# How to identify the compilation mode of Cross Platform assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to detect the compilation mode (debug/release/release-xml) of cross platform assemblies (XForms.Android / XForms.iOS/ XForms.UWP) by programatically?

I have tried with refer below links.

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToProgrammaticallyDetectIfAnAssemblyIsCompiledInDebugOrReleaseMode.aspx

This was working for all the assemblies except XForms.Android / XForms.iOS/ XForms.UWP assemblies.

Could you please provide me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to execute code for debug or release:

```
#if DEBUG
    // execute DEBUG code
#else
    // execute release code
#endif
```

Note that you need to make sure that the "Define DEBUG constant" is checked. Not sure how it is for Xamarin studio, but in Visual Studio you can find it in the project properties in the "build" tab:

[image]

You can find some further information about #if in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507704/will-if-release-work-like-if-debug-does-in-c).